# Terminology Clarification: "The curve is a function of x", means what?

Tags: calculus

A little confused as to what this really means. Can someone elaborate? [image]

Comment: A function is something that maps each element of a set (called the domain of the function) to exactly one element of another set (called the range or image of the function). You can tell that a graph in two dimensions is surely a function of x by checking that for each real number there's at most one point of the curve with that number as it's x coordinate. Sorry if I'm being unclear as I'm in a bit of a hurry, but if you need me to elaborate I'll get back and write a more thorough answer. :)

Comment: Maybe you should go back and find out what is meant by the word "function" in mathematics. Then you can answer the first question. Then find out what the "domain" and the "range" of a function are, and see whether you can answer the remaining questions by inspecting the figure. – Note that the circled red point is meant "to be not there".

Answer (score 0):

The vertical line test presumably means that for every $x$, the vertical line through $(x,0)$ intersects the curve exactly once. This means that there can be no ambiguity as to what value to assign to $f(x)$ when we want to define the value for $x$.